# DXA, File system publishing

Tags: dxa

In DXA, Can we publish Images to the Files system. If yes, we need to override the deployer Storage.conf.

2) If we can publish to File system how do we get rid of tcm id append to binary as we have css images that are handled from CMS.

3) How will the request to Binary from the file system is handled instead of going to Broker.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Client wants all the binary to be published to Filesystem

Comment: But why?  As mentioned, binaries are cached on file system, so performance can't be the reason...

Comment: Ok even though we publish to broker DB, how do we handle the css images, we need those images without tcm id's

Comment: @RickPannekoek, in my case the client wants the images to be served by simple Apache Httpd and not the application server. Having them all in the DB is restrictive and not desired by many.

Answer (score 3):

DXA expects all items (including binaries) to be published to the CD Broker database.  DXA will cache binaries on file system of the web application server.

Is there a reason why you want to publish to file system?

Comment: Client wants all the binary to be published to Filesystem

Comment: But why?  As mentioned, binaries are cached on file system, so performance can't be the reason...

Comment: Ok even though we publish to broker DB, how do we handle the css images, we need those images without tcm id's

Comment: And why are the TCM IDs in the file names considered problematic? The reason these are put in is to avoid file name uniqueness conflicts.

Comment: How do map css images that are used as background images in css? if we move from one environment to another then the tcm id changes, we need those images without tcm id so that we dont have to update css every time we move css from one environment to another

Comment: Ah, I'm starting to get it. I guess you're hitting this issue (which we intent to fix in the upcoming DXA 1.4 release): https://github.com/sdl/dxa-html-design/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

Css images are not published with tcm-id appended as they are part of htmldesign zip. and it doesn't make any sense because css assests are hard-coded in css file. Only content images are published with tcm-id.