# Assets published to File System not loading, gives 404

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.5

I am trying to publish the assets with extension .pdf to the file system and rest are going to Broker DB. But when I am trying to load the page on website, the PDF files are giving "File not found for Localization" Error.

I can see the file in the file system.

I did the settings in `cd_storage_conf.xml` file in deployer, discovery and session content services. I restarted the services & Application as well.

I am using SDL Web 8.1 & DXA 1.5

Deployer File Settings:

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile"
         defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\Site" />
</Storage>
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile"
         defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
    <Root Path="D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\Site\data" />
</Storage>
```

Publication Properties:
[image]

Please help.

Comment: Hi Could please share the deployer cd_storage_config.xml settings and publication property settings. seems issue with path.

Comment: What is path of pdf look like in source?

Comment: @Raj: \en\media\<PDF File Name.pdf>

Comment: @Meyank: Updated the question.

Comment: Also check http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13959/dxa-file-system-publishing?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing your cd_storage settings and publication property settings, it seems there is some issue with path.

I think your PDF files are deploying into following path eg: site/en/meida
So when you try to access this PDF's with root folder as "/en/media" it may conflicts with localization folder inside Binary folder.

Could you please try the below settings

```
 <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile"
             defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\Site\Asset" />
    </Storage>
```

Comment: Yes Meyank, you are right. I now configured the deployer to publish to assets folder, and customizing my DXA application to read pdfs from this location. This works fine

Answer (score 4):

DXA expects multimedia files published in Database. You can see this instruction at SDL Docs Url http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51. DXA caches multimedia files to the file system inside BinaryData folder. So first time your multimedia files served from Broker database otherwise from file system. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi Mukesh, this seems then a issue with DXA, as it should also handle the files on File System as well, specifically for PDFs/Videos of high size.

Comment: @SharadSangal binary content of high size is not something you should be storing in the CM database either, you should consider using an external system which is optimized for those type of large files, which you can then use in the CMS and Web Application again via ECL. Similar to how Media Manager works.